# Client Stubs from WSDL file using Maven plugin. Wsimport

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, maven-plugin, wsimport

I'm trying to generate client stubs for one of the Oracle's SOAP Web Service using maven. My console output says "Build Success" and a warning saying "The requested profile "pom.xml" could not be activated because it does not exist." when I run it using Maven generate sources.

I've tried wsimport and Apache's wsdl2java as well. Having the same issue there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.oracle.service</groupId>
    <artifactId>oracle.service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SOAPWebService2</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
         <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
           <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <executions>
             <execution>
               <goals>
                 <goal>wsimport</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                 <wsdlUrls>
                   <wsdlUrl>
                    https://ebmi-test.fin.us2.oraclecloud.com/publicFinancialCommonErpIntegration/ErpIntegrationService?WSDL
                   </wsdlUrl>
                 </wsdlUrls>
             <packageName>com.oracle.erp.stubs
             </packageName>
               </configuration>
             </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>            
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>


Console Output:
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building SOAPWebService2 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.748 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-11-30T12:12:38+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/147M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "pom.xml" could not be activated because it does not exist.
```

Also, I would appreciate it if anyone could give me a better idea about some reliable ways to generate Stubs in Eclipse Spring Tool Suite

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [Axis 2 Java generator plugin](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/eclipse/wsdl2java-plugin.html#WSDL2Java) which you can install in to Eclipse and generate the client stub for the wsdl. This reference document contains the perfect guid line with screen shots. You can refer it.